# Handling uploaded files in HTML form in django WITHOUT django forms

Tags: python, django, forms

The problem is that I have an HTML form that is generated dynamically, therefore I don't know how many file/text inputs are going to be there. So I decided not to use a form and handle file upload through request.FILES.

This is my code so far.

```
elif request.method == "POST":
        for ta in text_attachments:
            ta.text = request.POST["text-" + ta.id.__str__()]
            ta.save()
        for fa in text_attachments:
            if request.FILES.get("file-" + fa.id.__str__(), None):
                # fa.file = request.FILES["file-" + fa.id.__str__()]
                handle_uploaded_file(fa, request.FILES["file-" + fa.id.__str__()])
                fa.save()
```

And this is the handle_uploaded_file function:

```
def handle_uploaded_file(instance, f):
    path = coopertaion_attachment_path(instance, f.name)
    with open(path, 'wb+') as destination:
        for chunk in f.chunks():
            destination.write(chunk)
```

And this is the function that decides where the file should be uploaded.

```
def coopertaion_attachment_path(instance, filename):
    print("Filename: " + filename)
    os.umask(0)
    path = 'applications/cooperation/%s/' % instance.application.user.id
    att_path = os.path.join(settings.MEDIA_ROOT, path)
    if settings.DEFAULT_FILE_STORAGE == "django.core.files.storage.FileSystemStorage":
        if not os.path.exists(att_path):
            os.makedirs(att_path, 0o777)
            print("Creating path...")

    return os.path.join(path, filename)
```

In the end I always get this error:

```
[Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'applications/cooperation/1/filename.pdf'
```

Is it even possible to handle uploaded files without django form? How do I assign the uploaded file to a `FileField` of one of my models?

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be doing it right (file uploading and handling). Problem is in your `cooperation_attachment_path` method. You are returning `os.path.join(path, filename)` where `path` holds relative to your project path which does not exist hence the error.

> [Errno 2] No such file or directory:
>   'applications/cooperation/1/filename.pdf'

`att_path` holds absolute path so you should do:

```
return os.path.join(att_path, filename)
```